# Data not being updated/sent

Tags: php

PHP Version: 5.3.x

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['addbadge']))
{
$newbadge = $_POST['newbadge'];
$newcost = $_POST['newcost'];
    dbquery("INSERT INTO badge_shop (badge_id,cost) VALUES ('" . filter($newbadge) . "','" . filter($newcost) . "')");
    echo '<b>Added badge!</b>';
} // checked and complete

echo '<tr><form method="post" name="addbadge">
<td><center>?</center></td>
<td><input type="text" name="newbadge" value="" style="padding: 5px; font-size: 130%; text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="newcost" value="" style="padding: 5px; font-size: 130%; text-align: center;"></td>
<td><center><input type="submit" value="Add" onclick=""></center></td>
</form></tr>';
```

I don't know why it isn't updating into the database, although the other parts of my script work (removing, etc..) I am not sure as to the reason why it's not updating. If someone could shed some light as to why, that would be fantastic!

Comment: fyi, it might not be obvious, but this code might be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @DanielA.White how do you know how the filter() methods works?

Comment: @ronni I don't but it's not obvious to other readers

Comment: @DanielA.White oh, I missed the "might be"... one would expect the filter function to be a sanitizer... it might as well not be.. actully the filter() indicates it is being sanitized.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure, which db wrapper you are using, but you will need to first see where is the exact error.

First try to make a die if insert fails ...

dbisnert(insert query) or die('error in insert');

If it dies, Go ahead and handle the exception with try..catch block and throw the exception. If you dont see any exception then the syntax might have gone wrong. Please check in your logger file..

For timebeing enable display_errors in php.ini to see exact error.

I think this will help you to sort out issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is :
You are checking the form name is set or not as

`if(isset($_POST['addbadge']))`
 instead of that

give a name and id for the submit field as bellow

```
<input type="submit" value="Add" id="something" name="something" >
```

id and name may be same

And check as

```
if(isset($_POST['something']))
{
//your query comes here
}
```

Comment: or isset( $_POST['addbadge'],  $_POST['newbadge'])